# Bind directly to value property instead of ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angular

To bind the value of an input to a property, we use the ngModel directive. For example:

```
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='model' />
```

Why can't we simply use binding on the `value` property of the input element?

```
<input type='text' [(value)]='model' />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
<input type='text' [value]='model' (input)="model=$event" />
```

`[(value)]='model'` doesn't work because the `<input>` doesn't emit a `valueChange` event.

`ngModel` also provides forms integration which direct value binding doesn't.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way

`ngModel` uses provided `ControlValueAccessor`s, which are directives provided for all kinds of input elements (can also be a custom one for your own components) that acts as an adapter between `ngModel` and any component. This is to unify binding with all kinds of components and input elements.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.8/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/checkbox_value_accessor.ts#L17-L50

Comment: Isn't there a way to override this and tell Angular respond to a specific event?

Comment: <input> doesn't emit a valueChange event.

why?

Comment: Why do you expect a `valueChange` event? There is a `change` or `input` event that might do what you want. The supported events are listed in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event (names starting with on...). Perhaps you meant `valueChanges` from https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel. For that you need to add `<input ngModel (valueChanges)="handleTheEvent($event)/>"`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it but...

- Angular is famous for its inbuilt directives approach by using which you can manage/do lots of things.
- `ngModel` directive allows you to use **`one-way`** or **`two-way`** binding according to your need.
- Angular has inbuilt form-management system which is generally used with **`ngModel`** directive through which you can see whether any of form controls is **`valid`** or not and so **`form`** is valid or not.
- **`ngModel`** directive is built with **`Observable`** and **`Observer`** pattern which allows you to emit stream of data over the time.

In short there are lots of benefits given with **`ngModel`** directive so usually people prefer to use **`ngModel`** over **`value`** syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you can , but using `[value]` only like this

```
<input type='text' [value]='model' />
```

we use `[(ngModel)]` because it is a two way data binding, whereas `[value]` is one way binidng

when we use `[]` alongwith `()` it means it is two way binding.

apart from simply `(input)` there are no. of events are there in angular2 like `mouseover` `mouseout` etc.